# Pseudo cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $x_{j}$, ($j\geq j_{0}$ for some integer $j_{0}$) be a bounded sequence of reals such that $$|x_{j}-x_{j+1}|\to 0$$ and $$u(x_{j+1})\to \infty $$ for $j\to \infty$ where $u$ is a continuous function. How do I obtain a contradiction from this?

Comment: What is domain and image of $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open set you don't get a contradiction, because if $u: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being that
 $u(x) = 1/x$, then the sequence $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfies your conditions but $u(1/n) \rightarrow \infty$.

Otherwise, if $u: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, you argue like this. Using that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence then exists $M$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\subset$ $[-M,M]$. Once $[-M,M]$ is compact and $u$ is a continuous function then $u([-M,M]) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact set, then $u([-M,M])$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ the sequence $\{u(x_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, implying that is impossible $u(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.